# Notepad++ replace text between two strings spawning multiple lines and retain some part of the string in between

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have extracted many hive tables using show create table command.

The output is like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE MYSCHEMA.MyTABLE(
  `col1` string, 
  `col2` string)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `data_as_of_date` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'input.regex'='^(.*?)~}\\|(.*?)~}\\|(.*?)$') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  '/mnt/data/schema/layer/domain/MYTABLE'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'DO_NOT_UPDATE_STATS'='true', 
  'STATS_GENERATED_VIA_STATS_TASK'='true', 
  'last_modified_by'='user', 
  'last_modified_time'='1603077305', 
  'numRows'='23483974', 
  'parquet.compression'='SNAPPY', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1608243340');
```

I want to replace the text between...

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'input.regex'='^(.*?)~}\\|(.*?)~}\\|(.*?)$') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  '/mnt/data/schema/layer/domain/MYTABLE'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'DO_NOT_UPDATE_STATS'='true', 
  'STATS_GENERATED_VIA_STATS_TASK'='true', 
  'last_modified_by'='user', 
  'last_modified_time'='1603077305', 
  'numRows'='23483974', 
  'parquet.compression'='SNAPPY', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1608243340');
```

...to...

```
STORED AS PARQUET 
LOCATION '/mnt/data/schema/layer/domain/MYTABLE'
TBLPROPERTIES('parquet.compression'='SNAPPY');
```

...using Notepad++.

Here if you observe, the LOCATION parameter should remain same from the original and rest should be replaced as stated above. Basically, the replace is spawning across multiple lines and I am also retaining some part of the text. Someone please guide with the regex that I can use in Notepad++ (v7.8.2).

The final result should look like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE MYSCHEMA.MyTABLE(
      `col1` string, 
      `col2` string)
    PARTITIONED BY ( 
      `data_as_of_date` string)
STORED AS PARQUET 
LOCATION '/mnt/data/schema/layer/domain/MYTABLE'
TBLPROPERTIES('parquet.compression'='SNAPPY');
```

There are many tables and each table has a different LOCATION parameter. Do not want the LOCATION to be replaced as mentioned above.

It is also fine if I can do this in 2 parts. First replacing everything above LOCATION and then replacing the TBLPROPERTIES (if it cannot be done in single regex).

Comment: Yea, I noticed too many downvotes on regex questions myself, which I find unfortunate. Possibly because you did not show what you tried?

Comment: In your example, `LOCATION` is not the same before and after.

Comment: Oops! Sorry. I forgot to mock in all code snippets. That one is real location :). Let me edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `ROW FORMAT SERDE[\s\S]+?(LOCATION\s+.+\R)[\s\S]*?TBLPROPERTIES[^)]+?\);`
- Replace with: `STORED AS PARQUET \n$1TBLPROPERTIES\('parquet.compression'='SNAPPY'\);`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE        # literally
[\s\S]+?                # 1 or more any character, including newline, not greedy
(                       # group 1
LOCATION                # literally
\s+                     # 1 or more spaces
.+                      # 1 or more any character but newline
\R                      # any kind of linebreak
)                       # end group
[\s\S]*?                # 1 or more any character, including newline, not greedy
TBLPROPERTIES           # literally
[^)]+?                  # 1 or more any character that is not closing parenthesis
\);                     # closing parenthesis and semicolon
```

**Replacement:**

```
STORED AS PARQUET 
\n
$1
TBLPROPERTIES\('parquet.compression'='SNAPPY'\);
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Table properties are not in braces.

Comment: @vijayinani: Sorry, Notepad++ specific, parenthesis have to be escaped in the replacement part. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the same using two separate find and replace regex. Didn't knew it was going to be so simple with 2 times doing find and replace.

1. Replace: `ROW FORMAT SERDE.*?LOCATION`
   with: `STORED AS PARQUET\r\nLOCATION`
2. Replace: `TBLPROPERTIES.*?\)`
   with: `TBLPROPERTIES \(\r\n  'parquet.compression'='SNAPPY'\)`

I was having tough time to do this in single regex. Anyone?

Comment: Why have you unaccepted my answer? It does the job in a single regex and gives full explanation.

Comment: Changed it. Was by mistake. Can you like the question pls. Many people will be helpful.

Comment: And my answer too.